# Symbol.Imaging.Device.AvailableDevices throwing exception in windows mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-5.0

In  windows mobile 6.5 when Symbol.Imaging.Device.AvailableDevices is accessed it is throwing exception as 'IMAGE_FindFirst failed: Can't find PInvoke DLL 'ImgApi32.dll''. Can anyone tell what is going wrong or is there any way to include ImagApi32.dll in project.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your solution and select Add Reference.

[image: Add Reference]

Select your file:

[image: Select file]

I'm not sure what device you are using, but you might also want to see if there is a HotFix for it, like in these two devices:

- [MC9500-K Product HotFixes](http://support.symbol.com/support/browse.do?WidgetName=BROWSE_PRODUCT&TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&BROWSE_PRODUCT.isProductTaxonomy=true&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeId=SG_MC9500_KFIXES_1_2&BROWSE_PRODUCT.thisPageUrl=/product/products.do&id=m4&BROWSE_PRODUCT.TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&NodeType=leaf&NodeName=MC9500-K%20Fixes&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeType=leaf&NodeId=SG_MC9500_KFIXES_1_2&AppContext=AC_ProductPage&param_document=sp)
- [MC65 Product HotFixes](http://support.symbol.com/support/browse.do?WidgetName=BROWSE_PRODUCT&TaxoName=SG_SupportGoals&BROWSE_PRODUCT.isProductTaxonomy=true&BROWSE_PRODUCT.NodeId=SG_MC65FIXES_1_2&BROWSE_PRODUCT.thisPageUrl=/product/products.do&NodeType=leaf&NodeName=MC65%20Fixes&document=DT_SOFTWARE_1_1&NodeId=SG_MC65FIXES_1_2&AppContext=AC_ProductPage&param_document=sp)

Comment: Mobile model number is motorla ES400. I was unable to find ImgApi32.dll when trying to add it using references as you showed. Please give me link to download ImgApi32.dll.

Comment: If you do not have `ImgApi32.dll`, then why are you trying to **P/Invoke** it? I do not have the device you have, so I was just showing how to add it to your project. If you don't have that file, then you can not **P/Invoke** the file.

Comment: My app calling 'Symbol.Imaging.Device.AvailableDevices' to start camera. At this point only I am getting P/Invoke error. I am not explicitly P/Invokeing ImgApi32.dll. Searched Google, some forum said reinstall OS. Still I am getting the issue

Comment: I'm also trying to get the Motorola EMDK to work with my ES400, specifically the Imager API and have run into the same problem.  Were you able to find that .dll anywhere?

Comment: I never was able to find out what this Imager API was. My guess is it is a Windows 32 program, and not something compatible with Windows Mobile devices. Start a new thread, @nitewulf50, and tell the community what you are trying to do.